# How to write this doctrine query with multiple joins?

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine, query-builder, doctrine-query

I have an entity Person (p) which is related to an entity Notifications related to an entity NotificationType.

- Some persons have received a notification of type 1 (notification_type_id = 1).
- Some have received notifications but not of the type 1
- some haven't received messages at all.

Globally, I want to retrieve those who haven't received the messages of type 1.

I have written this query :

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
        ->leftJoin('p.notifications', 'n')
        ->leftJoin('p.notification_type', 'nt')
        ->addSelect(array('p','n','nt'))
        ->where('nt.id NOT IN (1)')
        ->orderBy('p.name', 'ASC');
return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

But with this query I only get those who have received notifications but not of type 1, I don't get those who haven't received notifications at all.

How can I rectify my query to have those ones ?

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

NOT IN with null values (for your joins where there are no messages) will not parse as you expect.  Similarly for eq or ne.

Try:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p');
$results = $qb->leftJoin('p.notifications', 'n')
              ->leftJoin('p.notification_type', 'nt')
              ->addSelect(array('p','n','nt'))
              ->where('nt.id !=1')
              ->orWhere('nt.id IS NULL')
              ->orderBy('p.name', 'ASC');
return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

You can also put these as conditions on your join, refer to [13.2.5. The Expr class](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/query-builder.html#the-expr-class) of the doctrine code

As an aside, you probably don't need the select since you can access those values programmatically via getters in the entity.